# Issue with virtual population in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongo DB with node.js and all models is in common folder and using virtual population to communicate between the models.For Example model1->model2->model3(model1 have the dependencies of model2 and model2 have the dependencies of model3).

Here is the code:

```
var packageGroupSchema = new Schema(
    {
        packageGroupCode: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        packageGroupName: { type: String, required: true },
        description: String,
        **moduleId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },**
        active: Boolean,
        createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
        lastUpdatedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
    },
    { 
        toJSON: { virtuals: true }
    }
);

packageGroupSchema.virtual('moduleData', {
  ref: 'Module', 
  localField: 'moduleId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true
});
```

2nd Model:

```
//module Schema
var moduleSchema = new Schema(
  {
      moduleCode: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
      moduleName: { type: String, required: true },
      description: String,
      **categoryId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },**
      active: Boolean,
      createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
      lastUpdatedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
  },
  { 
      toJSON: { virtuals: true }, 
      toObject: {virtuals: true}
  }
);

moduleSchema.virtual('categoryData', {
  ref: 'Category', 
  localField: 'categoryId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true
});
```

If I am runing the api for first model so I am geeting the data of dependencris(category) form the 2nd model.

Here is the result I am getting:

```
{
                "_id": "59410a5dab85113a7cdc0507",
                "packageGroupCode": "P02",
                "packageGroupName": "package2",
                "description": "package2",
                "moduleId": "5940efeadb8fe72a8cb4e056",
                "active": true,
                "__v": 0,
                "lastUpdatedDate": "2017-06-14T11:30:43.798Z",
                "createdDate": "2017-06-14T11:30:43.798Z",
                "moduleData": {
                    "_id": "5940efeadb8fe72a8cb4e056",
                    "moduleName": "module name",     
                     **"categoryData": null,**
                **"id": "5940efeadb8fe72a8cb4e056"**
            },
            **"id": "59410a5dab85113a7cdc0507"**
        }
```

Can anybody tell me what I have to do to ignore **catergoryData** in **moduleDate** and id repetition.

Expexted JSON should be like this:

```
{
                "_id": "59410a5dab85113a7cdc0507",
                "packageGroupCode": "P02",
                "packageGroupName": "package2",
                "description": "package2",
                "moduleId": "5940efeadb8fe72a8cb4e056",
                "active": true,
                "__v": 0,
                "lastUpdatedDate": "2017-06-14T11:30:43.798Z",
                "createdDate": "2017-06-14T11:30:43.798Z",
                "moduleData": {
                    "_id": "5940efeadb8fe72a8cb4e056",
                    "moduleName": "module name"
                }
            }
```

Comment: You do realize you are only "seeing" this because you specifically set `toJSON: { virtuals: true }` and same for `toObject`. With those turned off and/or basically not doing `console.log()` on the objects, then the accessors are in fact not present.

Comment: But for Module I need the access to see the Data.

Comment: What is your question? Are you not complaining that `categoryData` shows up as `null` here? Or are you "expecting" to see it populated, when you didn't actually ask for that to happen? Show the Query you are running that produces this result.

Comment: I am not expecting to see the categoryData to see in moduleData.....and the JSON getting need to send to the UI......Update the question with expected JSON.

Comment: So exactly what I said. Turn off `{ virtuals: true }` in the moduleSchema. You can actually invoke this manually, but that will be the simplest solution. It's perfectly valid, since it's no longer "virtual" once actually populated. That seems to be the part you are not getting.

Comment: After doing this, is it will be available in the UI.

Comment: Yes. The "virtuals" here is a legacy term that instead is referring to other functions to create "virtual fields". A "virtuals populate" is different, because you actually still call `.populate()` and the actual data ends up "merged" in the original object. So two different things once "populated". Here we "want to ignore" the data that is not populated yet. Get it?

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will try and check....

Answer (score 0):

if your result is stored in "theObject" you can remove the keys like this:

```
delete theObject["id"];
delete theObject["moduleData"]["id"];
delete theObject["moduleData"]["categoryData"];
```

Comment: In data base these entries are not there, after virtual population id is adding to json...